# Block the max number or Application that can run at one time

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I would like to limit the number of iexplorer.exe instances allowed to run on my computer. 
How could i do this? I was thinking of running a bat file when the computer starts up?

The ultimate goal is to restrict the max number of internet explorers that can be open at any given time.

Comment: This question doesn't sound like a good fit for Stack Overflow, but should perhaps be asked on http://superuser.com or perhaps http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run IE with a batch file using its command-line options:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx

But, IE versions 8+ follow a model where tabs are isolated from the frame, and are located in separate processes so it will be difficult for you to identify which iexplorer.exe process is a tab or a new window:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx

I mean, technically anything is possible and perhaps you can go deeper into the Windows core to control the processes but, do you really wanted to go that far?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I dont want to spend a ton of time on this i was just looking for a simple fix to set a max number or iexplorer.exe that were allowed to run.  I guess i will just continue to drill them no more then 5 at a time lol thank you for your help